# Why doesn't this code check the validity of a word in a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey guys I'm having a bit of trouble for checking the validity of a word in scrabble. For my code, It just goes to the "else" statement so I dont think it even checked the dictionary (which is a seperate text) file anyway. Can anyone correct my errors?

```
def dictionary_check(user_word):
    dictionary = open("dictionary.txt", "r")
    for line in dictionary:
        line = line.split()
        if user_word.upper() == line:
            print("word is valid")
            return
    print("never heard of this word")


myTiles = ["B","S","N","O","E","U","T"]

user_word = "BEN"

dictionary_check(user_word)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have:

```
line = line.split()
    if user_word.upper() == line:
```

`line.split()` outputs a list of words, not a single word. If user_word is a string, your if statement will never be True. Instead, you should be iterating over all the words and not just the lines that they are on:

```
def dictionary_check(user_word):
    dictionary = open("dictionary.txt", "r")
    for line in dictionary:
        line = line.split()
        for word in line:
            if user_word.upper() == word: #if word found say its its found
                print("word is valid")
                return #end the function because it doesn't need to keep going
    print("never heard of this word") #it went through all the words and it wasn't found
```

Of course, there are much faster ways to do this task than to open a file each time you need to check. You can load all of the words into memory at the start of your file, so each check for a word being in the dictionary is done in constant time:

```
#loading words into memory
dictionary = set()
with open("dictionary.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in dictionary:
        for word in line.split():
            dictionary.add(word)
```

Now you can check if any word is in the dictionary with:

```
if word in dictionary:
    ...
```